# Low Quality Rendering Rotating Images

Tags: java, swing, graphics, rotation, jframe

I have a `JFrame`, and periodically I paint a PNG image on screen using `paintComponent`. The image rotates following the mouse pointer.
When the image rotates the quality it's just terrible (in the photo).

The PNG is 20x10 pixels.

[image: Photo Quality]

What to do?

```
//Rotating System
backup = g2d.getTransform();
a = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(turret.angle), turret.x, turret.y);
g2d.setTransform(a);
g2d.drawImage(turret.sprite, (int) turret.x - 6, (int) turret.y - 15, null);
g2d.setTransform(backup);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Comment: if quality is your concern either use higher resolution images and anti aliasing or use vector graphics instead ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it will help but you can try changing some of the Graphics properties. For example:

```
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```